# Al leer una cadena de caracteres en una estructura desaparece el primer caracter

Tags: c++, array, string, estructuras-de-datos, struct

Al leer una cadena de caracteres en un array de estructura desaparece el primer caracter, pero solo en la primera posición del array.

Para ser más precisos, en `h1[i].titulo`, si por ejemplo pongo `Leer`, el programa leerá `eer`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


struct HabitoCuantitativo{
    int objetivo;
    char unidad[20];
};

struct fecha{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anho;
};

struct Habito{
    char titulo[30];
    char descripcion[200];
    struct fecha date;
    struct HabitoCuantitativo objetivos;
}h1[3];


int main(){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout << "---------Habito " << i+1 << "---------" << endl;
        cout << "Nombre del habito: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(h1[i].titulo, 30);
        cout << "Descripcion del habito: ";
        cin.getline(h1[i].descripcion, 200);
        cout << "Objetivo del habito (numero): ";
        cin >> h1[i].objetivos.objetivo;
        cout << "Unidad del objetivo: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(h1[i].objetivos.unidad, 20);
        cout << "Dia del habito: ";
        cin >> h1[i].date.dia;
        cout << "Mes del habito: ";
        cin >> h1[i].date.mes;
        cout << "Anho del habito: ";
        cin >> h1[i].date.anho;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout << "---------Habito " << i+1 << "---------" << endl;
        cout << h1[i].titulo << endl;
        cout << h1[i].descripcion << endl;
        cout << h1[i].objetivos.objetivo << endl;
        cout << h1[i].objetivos.unidad << endl;
        cout << h1[i].date.dia << "/" << h1[i].date.mes << "/" << h1[i].date.anho << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el uso de [`cin.ignore()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/), de la documentación en cplusplus.com

Declaración de la función:

> `istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);`

Explicación

> Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them, until either n characters have been extracted, or one compares equal to delim....

O sea que básicamente, cuando escribes

```cpp
cout << "Nombre del hábito: ";
cin.ignore(); // <- aquí estás descartando el primer caracter
cin.getline(h1[i].titulo, 30);
```

Estás descartando el primer caracter que exista en el buffer, por eso te sale `eer` en vez de `Leer`.

De la [documentación](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) de `cin.getline()` en cplusplus.com

> Extracts characters from the stream as unformatted input and stores them into s as a c-string, until either the extracted character is the delimiting character, or n characters have been written to s (including the terminating null character).

> The delimiting character is the newline character ('\n') for the first form, and delim for the second: when found in the input sequence, it is extracted from the input sequence, but discarded and not written to s.

Básicamente, la función va a leer y guardar `n - 1` caracteres (1 caracter reservado para `\0`), o `k <= n - 1` números de caracteres que se encuentren antes del *delimiter* '\n', y va a descartar dicho caracter.

Entonces, no hay necesidad de utilizar `cin.ignore()` (supongo que lo utilizabas para descartar LF de la última línea), el código funciona "bien" así

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
        char titulo[30];
        char desc[200];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                std::cout << "---------Hábito " << i+1 << "---------" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Nombre del hábito: ";
                std::cin.getline(titulo, 30);
                std::cout << "Descripcion del hábito: ";
                std::cin.getline(desc, 200);
                std::cout << std::endl << "Título: \"" << titulo << "\" Descripción: \"" << desc << '"' << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Sin embargo, este código no está muy bien porque si el usuario ingresa 30 o más caracteres el programa va a fallar, inténtalo así

`g++ hola.cpp -o hola.out && echo "123456789012345678901234567890" | ./hola.out`

Verás que el output es el siguiente

```
---------Hábito 1---------
Nombre del hábito: Descripcion del hábito: 
Título: "12345678901234567890123456789" Descripción: ""
---------Hábito 2---------
Nombre del hábito: Descripcion del hábito: 
Título: "" Descripción: ""
---------Hábito 3---------
Nombre del hábito: Descripcion del hábito: 
Título: "" Descripción: ""
```

El cual, asumo que no es el deseado, pero ¿por qué pasa eso?

De la [documentación](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

> The failbit flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to s. Note that if the character that follows those (n-1) characters in the input sequence is precisely the delimiting character, it is also extracted and the failbit flag is not set (the extracted sequence was exactly n characters long).

Entonces, en el caso anterior, se leen los 30+ caracteres, y *flag failbit* se coloca, lo que hace que subsecuentes llamadas en `cin` no "funcionen" como lo esperabas.

Entonces, hay que limpiar ese flag, antes de continuar

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
        char titulo[30];
        char desc[200];
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                std::cout << "---------Hábito " << i+1 << "---------" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Nombre del hábito: ";
                std::cin.getline(titulo, 30);
                if (std::cin.fail()) { // revisar si el failbit es on
                        std::cout << "Sólo se permiten 29 caracteres, recortando el string a: \"" << titulo << '"'  << std::endl;
                        std::cin.clear(); // <- limpiar el failbit, para que otras operaciones sucedan correctamente
                        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // <- limpiar la línea ingresada en el buffer
                }
                std::cout << "Descripcion del hábito: ";
                std::cin.getline(desc, 200);
                std::cout << std::endl << "Título: \"" << titulo << "\" Descripción: \"" << desc << '"' << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Revisando con `cin.fail()` si el *failbit* se puso, "reseteando" los flags con `cin.clear()` y "eliminando" o "descartando" el resto de caracteres ingresados en esa línea con `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. Revisar el comportamiento del programa sin `cin.ignore` e ingresa por ejemplo `12345678901234567890123456789holamundo` para que veas qué sucede.

Y entonces sí, el comportamiento del programa es el esperado. Obviamente habría que pulirlo más, pero creo que con eso es suficiente para responder la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
     cin.ignore();
```

Aquí ignoras el primer carácter que tienes en el stream. Eso nos viene de maravilla para las lecturas con el `cin.getline`, ya que si nos queda el `\n` después de las lecturas con el `cin.operator>>()`.

Tu problema es que en la primera lectura, el mero primer carácter que introduzcas será ignorado. Por eso es que pasa de `Leer` a `eer` en la primera lectura.

Lo que tienes que hacer es no ejecutarlo en la primera vuelta. Asi:

```
if (i != 0) {
    cin.ignore();
}
```